# Are joda timezone ids the same as java time zone ids?

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

I'm using the ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED intent filter on Android to respond to a timezone change.

I noticed that Jodas current timezone is not updated at this time using: 
`DateTimeZone.getDefault()`

When I use Java's default `TimeZone.getDefault()`, the timezone is correct.

Notice: When I change it again: Joda has the value I changed it to before. So it is behind (not yet updated when Android fires the Broadcast Intent).

So I only can use the Java timezone for current timezone. But my domain object uses Joda DateTimeZone`s. Now I want to compare current timezone with the one in my domain object. Is it save to do this:

```
TimeZone currenTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
if(action.getLocation().getDateTimeZone().getID().equals(currenTimeZone.getID()))) {
 [...]
}
```

? 
Or can the timezone ids differ between the two libraries?

Comment: Edit your Question to include specific values at issue, if you want more helpful answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

**No, not safe** to assume a time zone:

- exists.
- has a particular identifier defined.
- has the same definition/rules.

## *tzdata*

Most operating systems and software libraries rely on the [*tz database*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) maintained by [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority) to supply current and past time zone information. Also known as `tzdata` or `TZDB`. Formerly known as the *Olson Database*.

## Frequent changes

Around the world, **politicians enjoy frequently changing**, redefining, rescheduling, renaming, and otherwise messing around with time zone definitions and rules. They often do so with little forewarning, such as less that two months now in [Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Turkey) (autumn of 2016).

Sometimes new time zones are defined. So in that regard, to answer your Question specifically: Yes, some copies of tzdata may have newer time zone definitions that do not exist in older copies, so there may a difference of time zone identifiers.

Also, new names are sometimes given to existing time zones. For example, with India recently restoring their city names, `Asia/Calcutta` is now also labeled as `Asia/Kolkota`. Again, old tzdata copies will not know of this newer name.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Some software will extend the tzdata to try to recognize these pseudo-time zones. Not a good idea. But, again, this means using these non-standard time zone identifiers might work in one place but not another. Stick with the official time zone names.

Some zones have a [display name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-), such as `British Time`. But you should *never* use that as an identifier.

## Updating

System administrators must make the effort to update the tzdata in all the various places it might be used:

- Operating system
- Java Virtual Machine
- Software libraries (such as Joda-Time, and possibly [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)).

Providers of JVMs usually include a recent version of the tzdata in updates to the JVMs. But politicians twiddle with time zones more often than Java updates. So you may need to manually update the JVM. Oracle provides the [*Timezone Update Tool*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) for Oracle & OpenJDK JVMs.

Joda-Time includes its own copy of tzdata. So you will need to either update your Joda-Time library or do a manual replacement of the tzdata. Note that the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance-mode, and advises moving to the java.time classes bundled with Java 8 and later.

## List known identifiers

The java.time classes can show you a list of their [known zone identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds--).

```
Set<String> zoneIds = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds() ;
```

Other libraries and operating systems may be able to do the same.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

So your use of [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) is now outmoded by [`ZoneId.systemDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--):

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
String zoneIdentifier = z.toString() ;
```

Using that to get current moment in a particular zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```